# Is it legal to create your own stm 32 board

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, stm32, power-electronics, embedded

Is it legal to create your own board containing STM 32 controller and advertise it commercially?

I have made a custom board and want to advertise it - is it OK? Any legal/copyright issues? If yes how do I address them so that I can advertise safely?

Comment: Uhhh I would hope so...since you know...that's the whole pointing of manufacturing and selling the STM32 processor.

Comment: There may be legal issues of regulatory approval on safety, EMC etc, depending on jurisdiction. Often can be worked round with a disclaimer "this is a component, not a complete product or system : it is up to the customer to comply with appropriate regulations". Safety can be worked round by having no high voltages, no high currents or temperatures, no lead, etc and at least in the EU, self certifying to that effect. RF emissions, immunity, similar applies.

Answer (score 5):

Probably de facto legal, but if you copied someone else's layout, infringed their patents or trademarks, infringed copyright on their firmware/software (if any), copied their photos, made it look like someone else's product so that customers might be confused, or are in breach of any of the various laws that might be in your jurisdiction on EMI emissions, mains voltage connection, Pb or other allegedly hazardous materials content etc. it might not be.

And that's without even getting into potential consumer protection laws. Sometimes it's cheaper to give things away than to take  money.

Comment: Also don't claim to own the STM32 architecture or anything, obviously.

Answer (score 4):

Sure! After all, ST wants to sell chips. Also most of the time, chip manufacturers don't profit that much or at all on dev boards (some are even sold at a loss) so I don't see why they would reject the free publicity.

Assuming ST accepts reuse of parts of the reference design because that sells chips, 
the only part that could cause trouble would be the name, so make sure the name is not already copyrighted. For example don't call it "nucleo".

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can create your own designs using the STM32 components available from the manufacturer. What you would want to avoid is making an exact copy of one of ST Micro's STM 32 evaluation boards or development modules unless you have written approval and agreement from the manufacturer that such direct copy is allowed.

Beyond this there is the whole gambit of techniques, design rules, quality, reliability and regulatory requirements that you would have to navigate through in preparing any product for the market.

Comment: It is likely true regarding the "exact copy of the entire eval borad". However any custom design will have some functional add-ons, which will make it not "exact copy". If fact, exact copy of board layout and component selection is strongly encouraged by chipmakers, since it simplifies bring-up/debug efforts on customer's side, and speeds up time-to-market.